# Meaning of a "Standby" in this case

Tags: word-meaning

> “I haven’t got a clue what this lot’s supposed to mean,” he said,
> staring down at a long list of calculations.
> “You know,” said Ron, whose hair was on end because of all the  times he had run his fingers through it in
> frustration, “I think it’s back  to the old **Divination standby**.”
> “What – make it up?”
> “Yeah,” said Ron

What does "*standby*" mean in the above context. Does it mean not doing anything as I think.

Comment: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/standby

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 'standby' is something that is ready to be used at any time -- it is 'standing by' the situation, and might or might not be put into operation. You can (or could) buy 'standby' tickets for airline flights, and in that case were able to fly if there was a seat available after all regular ticket holders were seated just before the plane took off.

In this case, "Divination standby" refers to their method of inventing things to tell the teacher of the Divination class (I remember this scene); 'making it up' is a method that is always ready, and they use it when they have to.